# How to call an external php file inside a Wordpress plugin using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am new at coding a Wordpress plugin, so in this case I need to use a file called action_save_data.php located in the includes folder inside the Plugin folder.

so the plugin code looks like this:

```
<?php
  /**
  * Plugin Name: ETBO test
  * Plugin URI:  http://cma-ecg.com/ebot/
  * Text Domain: ETBO-TEST
  * License:     GPL-2.0+
  * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
  */

 add_shortcode('etbo_test' , 'render_test');

 function render_test(){ 


 ?>
  <html lang="en" >
     // All the Html Code here...
 

   <script src="wp-content/plugins/etbo/assets/js/wizard-3.js"></script>

</html>
 <?php 
  }
  ?>
```

and inside the wizard-3.js file I have this code:

```
function saveData(){

var data = $("#kt_form").serialize();
         
        
          
           $.ajax({
            
                       type : 'POST',
                       url  : 'includes/action_save_data.php',
                       data: data, 
                       success :  function(response)
                          {      
                             if(response==1){
                                 
                                 Swal.fire({
                                        text: "Resultados Guardados y Enviados por Correo.",
                                        icon: "success",
                                        buttonsStyling: false,
                                        confirmButtonText: "Ok, entendido!",
                                        customClass: {
                                            confirmButton: "btn font-weight-bold btn-primary",
                                        }
                                    });
                                 
                             }else{
                                 
                                 alert(response);
                             }
                          }
                          
                });

              }
```

The console log says that the action_save_data.php file is not found, I know the file exits on that folder so How to include it ?
Thanks in  advance

Comment: Is the file inside a folder called `includes` in the websites root folder? If so, try `url: '/includes/action_save_data.php'`. Without the initial `/`, the browser will append the URL to the current page's URL. If you, for example, are on page  `example.com/foo`, the browser will try and fetch it from `example.com/foo/includes/action_save_data.php`. With the initial `/`, the browser will ignore the current page's URL.

Comment: the folder called includes is inside the plugin folder

Comment: Then you need to use the complete path from the web servers root folder (also called "document root" and isusually where you have your `index.php` in a normal WP install). Something like. `url: '/wp-content/plugins/the-plugin-name/includes/action_save_data.php'`. I haven't used WP in a while so don't trust me on the exact URL. It's just an example.

Comment: I still get this as response: ERROR : -> No such file or directory

Comment: _"so in this case I need to use a file called action_save_data.php located in ..."_ - you really should not be targeting script files directly. The _correct_ way to handle this, is to set up an AJAX endpoint. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: _"so the plugin code looks like this:"_ - also bad. You wrote this is part of a shortcode, and shortcodes are usually executed somewhere within the page content generation context. So your `<html lang="en" >/ All the Html Code here... </html>` is likely to write this somewhere into an already existing template, creating _duplicates_ of elements that must occur only once (such as `html`, `head`, `body`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a Javascript variable `var ajax_target = "<?php echo plugins_url( './includes/action_save_data.php', __FILE__ ) ?>"` right before loading the js file and then use this variable in the AJAX code in the JS file as following.
`$.ajax({

```
                   type : 'POST',
                   url  : ajax_target,
```

....................`